# Unable to access redux props

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

When a user logs in to the app, their information (username, email, etc) is saved in redux. I am able to log in, but my issue is accessing the actual information after logging in.

Here is the code where I am trying to access redux:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  user: state.user,
});


class LikeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      likerUID: Firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
      likerUsername: this.props.user.username, //<------------------ Issue is here
```

Error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.user.username')
```

How I save the information to redux when a user is authenticated:

```
dispatch(authUser(Firebase.auth().currentUser.uid, Firebase.auth().currentUser.email, doc.data().username));
```

Finally my redux actions:

```
export const authUser = (userid, userEmail, username) => (dispatch) => {
  const data = {
    id: userid,
    username,
    email: userEmail,
  };
  dispatch(setAuthUser(data));
};
```

In my redux "authUser", I added the line `console.log(username);` which properly logs the username:

```
export const authUser = (userid, userEmail, username) => (dispatch) => {
  const data = {
    id: userid,
    username,
    email: userEmail,
  };

  console.log(username);
  dispatch(setAuthUser(data));
};
```

So the issue is with accessing it, not setting it.

Comment: Is the component shown before the user is logged in? Because you are getting the value in the constructor, it is fetched when the component is first shown, and is never updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  user: state.UserReducer.user,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Don't Store Props in State

It is not a good idea to put values from `this.props` into `this.state`.  Your state will save the very first value of `this.props.user.username` that it sees.  It will not update with new values.

Your `constructor` function runs and sets the state before the user has logged in so `this.props.user` is `undefined` and attempting to access `this.props.user.username` is an error ("TypeError: undefined is not an object").

Instead, you want to access the username **directly from the props** when you need to use it.  That way you always get the current value from Redux.  You can combine with the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `?.` to avoid errors if the `user` is `undefined`.

```
const likerUsername = this.props.user?.username;
```